# Не видна созданная консольная команда

Tags: php, yii

Взял за основу приложение "blog" из папки demos, создал в protected папку commands, а там - файл products_import.php.

Вот его содержимое:

```
<?php
class ProductsImportCommand extends CConsoleCommand {
public function actionIndex() {
try {
  $products = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
      ->select('product.id, product.url, product.name, product.price, product.price_old, product_section.name, product_category.name, product_img.name')
    ->from('product')
      ->join('product_assignment, product_section, product_category, product_img', 'product.id=product_assignment.product_id AND product_section.id=product_assignment.section_id AND product_category.id=product_assignment.category_id')
      ->order('product_img.type desc')
      ->queryAll();

  $output = fopen('product_import.csv', 'w', ',');
  fputcsv($output, array('product.id', 'product.url', 'product.name', 'product.price', 'product.price_old', 'product_section.name', 'product_category.name', 'product_img.name'));
  foreach($products as $product) {
      fputcsv($output, $product);
    }

    fclose($output);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Потом попытался запустить yicc ProductsImport index, но ничего не создается, в консоли же пишет, что доступно лишь 4 стандартные команды yiic.
В чем может быть проблема?

UPD: Теперь работает. Но где в коде SQL-запроса может быть ошибка, подскажите, пожалуйста? Если его закомментировать - создается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мне память не изменяет, то нужно в конфиге прописать путь к файлу с классом команды.

```
'commandMap' => [
        'customCommand' => [
            'class' => /*path*/,
            //params => value, ...
        ],
```

Comment: Сейчас мой файл конфигурации console.php содержит: <?php

// This is the configuration for yiic console application.
// Any writable CConsoleApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
 'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
 'name'=>'My Console Application',
);

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, тут возможно понятнее будет. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CConsoleApplication#commandMap-detail

Comment: Да, большое спасибо! Теперь работает. Но где в коде SQL-запроса может быть ошибка, подскажите, пожалуйста? Если его закомментировать - создается.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш файл должен называться так же как и класс внутри него `ProductsImportCommand.php`

Comment: Спасибо, верно. Теперь работает. Но где в коде SQL-запроса может быть ошибка, подскажите, пожалуйста? Если его закомментировать - создается.

Comment: Это не относиться к изначальному вопросу, выберите правильный ответ и создайте отдельный вопрос. А так ищете ваши ошибки в логах, сами ведь написали `$this->logger->error($e->getMessage());`